# Fastest Way for Comparing Strings Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, comparison, string-comparison

Situation: Comparing strings in fileA with pre-defined strings in fileB. Example of said function in my code:

```
string = open('fileA', 'r')
stringlist = open('fileB', 'r')

//compare the strings
for i in string:
    for j in stringlist:
        if i == j:
            print("Same String found!" + i + " " + j)
```

Problem: In my actual program, `string` contains more than 200 strings, while `stringlist` is a file with more than 50,000 strings. The nested for loop, as I have read, is slow as a comparison function.

Question: What is the fastest way to compare the two files' content?

Additional information 1: Both files are CSV files, and are opened in my program as CSV-delimited.

Additional information 2: Strings are md5 hashes (32 characters).

Additional information 3: I am open to other ways to store the strings, i.e. Compare the strings on-the-fly instead of saving it to fileA.

Additional information 4: I am also open to other methods or modules that I can use (i.e.: Threading/parallel processing) -- speed is the key here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
setA = set(listA)
setB = set(listB)
common = setA.intersection(setB)
```

`common` now holds all the strings that are present in both lists

You can also do this with a one-liner:

```
common = set(listA).intersection(set(listB))
```

If you can do this comparison "on the fly" it is of course better and faster than saving the lists to a file and then reading again from that file, you gain nothing by doing that.

And of course, to print duplicates:

```
for x in common:
    print(x)
```

Comment: I am only generating `strings`. `stringlist` is a file that is downloaded from the internet. I do have plans to load it to RAM for supposedly faster access

Comment: Then don't save `string` to file and load `stringlist` to memory like you said, that is optimal. as long as `stringlist` file isn't too big for your memory to contain

Comment: one last question: So I can use threading like this for optimal speed?:
thread1 = //hash; thread2 = //compare; //pass thread1 to thread2; //thread2 compares while thread1 hashes a new file

Comment: you can do something like that with a little effort, yes, but for file sizes that you mentioned the gain in speed will not be large in comparison to the `set` example

Comment: Also, re-edited my answer to show how to `common` list, but that was probably obvious

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with not printing duplicates, using [set.intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) should be really fast:

```
list1 = ["hello", "world", "foo"]
list2 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

set(list1).intersection(list2)
# {'foo'}
```

Comment: If I want to print the duplicates is there a way?

Comment: @TimothyWongGlash I can't think of another way than using list comprehensions. `[s for s in list1 if s in list2]` but this doesn't account the duplicates (repetitions) in list2. So you need to do a second loop which gives cluttered results and similar in performance to the question. Maybe you can use `collections.Counter` to find how many duplicates there are and print accordingly but that would not be in same order.